# How to format (transform) laravel database paginated results?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For example i have following code:

```
public function index()
{
    return
        Model::select(['id', 'some_field', ...// more some fields])
            ->with('data') // load relation
            ->paginate(20);
}
```

How do i format (transform/manipulate on) obtained data from database?

CakePHP ORM have useful method for this -https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields
&& https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce

But i can't find any thing, that can help me to do a same things in Laravel.
I can override "toArray" method in a model, but this will affect all application parts (not only an index action in my controller).

Comment: You can use `map` on the returned collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do same thing in `Laravel`, for example:

```
return Model::select(['id', 'some_field', ...// more some fields])
->with('data')
->paginate(20)
->map(function($item, $key) {
    // Some pseudo code
    $item->uid = uniqid();

    // Must return the $item
    return $item;
});
```

There are other ways doing similar things. You can do many more in [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods). There is a [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-transform) method as well, among many.

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I used map it returned as a collection instead of a paginated resource

Comment: @SalustianoMuniz both `map` and `transform` will not work. You should use `through` which is supported in `AbstractPaginator`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to only modify items without loosing the pagination data

```
public function index()
{
    $data_with_pagination = Model::select(['id', 'some_field', ...// more some fields])
        ->with('data') // load relation
        ->paginate(20);

    foreach ($data_with_pagination->items() as $item) {
        // modify your item here
        $item['uid'] = uniqid();
    }

    return $data_with_pagination;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`paginate()` and `get()` will return a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) giving you access to all the [`Collection` methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods).

You would be able to do:

```
public function index()
{
    return
        Model::select(['id', 'some_field', ...// more some fields])
            ->with('data') // load relation
            ->paginate(20)
            ->map(function($model) {
                $model->total_things = $model->one_thing + $model->other_thing;
                return $model;
            });
}
```

Comment: Using this will lose all the total counts and pagination URLs that it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers already provided will work, but will return a collection instead of a paginated resource.
The trick is to use the `tap` helper method before `map`'ping, to return the same object you modified.

```
   public function index()
    {
        return tap(Model::select(['id', 'some_field', ...// more some fields])
            ->with('data') // load relation
            ->paginate(20))
            ->map(function ($model) {
                $model->something_to_format = someFormattingHelper($model->something_to_format);
                return $model;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if anyone still needs this.
But I found another solution. It's not the best solution, but it gets the job done.

Both the transform() and map() functions are supported.
Here's the link: https://jnbrnplbr.medium.com/transform-map-laravel-paginated-collection-b1ab912d7996

Answer (score 0):

`map` or `transform` will not work.
You should use `through` which is supported in `AbstractPaginator` as specified in [laravel official api](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6ba2ccb3000cd40b634863c4278344f0e0d6c2c5/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L345).

Ex:

```
User::filter($request->all()
   ->with('applications')
   ->paginate(config('app.defaults.pageSize'))
   // through() will call transform() on the $items in the pagination object
   ->through(function ($user, $key) {
      $user['picture'] = $user->avatar;

      return $user;
   });
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65560742/11297747